# Json Insertion error while parsing in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am getting this error
Error : Array to string conversion in pathname on line 37

---

```
<?php
  include('config.php');
    // read json file
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
    $filename = 'employee.json';
    $json_data = file_get_contents($filename);   
    // $json_data=$_POST['QUESTION'];
    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($json_data,true);

if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
{
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($data);$j++){
        //$jsonData[$j] = $data[$j]['DATA'];
        //$jsonAnswers[$j] = $data[$j]['ANSWERS'];

        $drmobile = $data[$j]['DATA']['DRMOBILE'];
        $divcode = $data[$j]['DATA']['DIVCODE'];
        $brdcode = $data[$j]['DATA']['BRDCODE'];
        $prdcode = $data[$j]['DATA']['PRDCODE'];
        $createdon = $data[$j]['DATA']['CREATEDON'];

    //  echo $drmobile." -- ";
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data[$j]['ANSWERS']);$i++)
        {

            $quecode[$i] = $data[$j]['ANSWERS'][$i]['ADCODE'];
            $answer[$i] = $data[$j]['ANSWERS'][$i]['ANSWER'];

            // $quecodes=$quecode[$i];
            // $answers=$answer[$i];
            echo $quecode[$i]." <--> ".$answer[$i]."<br/>";
        }
        echo "<br/>-----------<br/>";
        $sql="INSERT INTO U_ANSWERS(DRMOBILE,ADCODE,DIVCODE,BRDCODE,PRDCODE,ANSWERS,CREATEDON)
        VALUES ('$drmobile', '$quecode', '$divcode', '$brdcode', '$prdcode', '$answer', '$createdon');";
            $qur = mysql_query($sql);
        if($qur){
        $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Done User added!");
    }else{
        $json = array("status" => 2, "msg" => "Already Submitted");
    }


    }


}

}else{
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
}


@mysql_close($conn);

/* Output header */
// header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);    
    //close connection
 ?>
```

Sample Json

```
[{
    "DATA": {
        "DRMOBILE": "8985180306",
        "DIVCODE": 2,
        "BRDCODE": 2,
        "PRDCODE": 2,
        "CREATEDON": "2017-08-10 11:38:22"
    },
    "ANSWERS": [{
        "ADCODE": 1,
        "ANSWER": "Excellent"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 2,
        "ANSWER": "Yes"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 3,
        "ANSWER": "No"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 4,
        "ANSWER": "Yes"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 5,
        "ANSWER": "Yes"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 6,
        "ANSWER": "No"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 7,
        "ANSWER": "2-4"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 8,
        "ANSWER": "15"
    }]
},{
    "DATA": {
        "DRMOBILE": "8985180305",
        "DIVCODE": 1,
        "BRDCODE": 1,
        "PRDCODE": 1,
        "CREATEDON": "2017-08-10 11:38:22"
    },
    "ANSWERS": [{
        "ADCODE": 1,
        "ANSWER": "Excellent"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 2,
        "ANSWER": "Yes"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 3,
        "ANSWER": "No"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 4,
        "ANSWER": "Yes"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 5,
        "ANSWER": "Yes"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 6,
        "ANSWER": "No"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 7,
        "ANSWER": "2-4"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 8,
        "ANSWER": "15"
    }]
},{
    "DATA": {
        "DRMOBILE": "8985180307",
        "DIVCODE": 2,
        "BRDCODE": 2,
        "PRDCODE": 2,
        "CREATEDON": "2017-08-10 11:38:22"
    },
    "ANSWERS": [{
        "ADCODE": 1,
        "ANSWER": "Excellent"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 2,
        "ANSWER": "Yes"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 3,
        "ANSWER": "No"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 4,
        "ANSWER": "Yes"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 5,
        "ANSWER": "Yes"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 6,
        "ANSWER": "No"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 7,
        "ANSWER": "2-4"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 8,
        "ANSWER": "15"
    }]
}
]
```

---

Comment: Which is line 37? Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\android\testing\krisapp\test3.php on line 37 this is the error message am getting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think this error is because you pass these arrays

```
 $quecode[$i] = $data[$j]['ANSWERS'][$i]['ADCODE'];
  $answer[$i] = $data[$j]['ANSWERS'][$i]['ANSWER'];
```

here :

```
 VALUES ('$drmobile', '$quecode', '$divcode', '$brdcode', '$prdcode', 
'$answer', '$createdon');
```

so should pass this:

```
VALUES ('$drmobile', '$quecode[$i]', '$divcode', '$brdcode', '$prdcode', 
'$answer[$i]', '$createdon');
```

Comment: yes your suggestion is right but we should place the sql statement in the loop as M Idrees said

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, it shows that `$quecode` and `$answer` are arrays.

And in your SQL statement, you are using these as string variables.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO U_ANSWERS(DRMOBILE,ADCODE,DIVCODE,BRDCODE,PRDCODE,ANSWERS,CREATEDON)
        VALUES ('$drmobile', '$quecode', '$divcode', '$brdcode', '$prdcode', '$answer', '$createdon');";
```

Now there could be two possible ways:

1. Put this SQL statement also in loop, and insert all individual
   values from these arrays (`$quecode` and `$answer`)
2. Combine these (`$quecode` and `$answer`) array's values into a single string (e.g., comma
   separated string) by using `implode` function like: `implode(",", $quecode);` and then insert as single string as you are using now.

Comment: i have placed the sql statement in the loop but same error repeats Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\android\testing\krisapp\test3.php on line 34 and the data is inserting into the table but the quecode is inserted as 0 and answer as array @ M Idrees

Comment: Can you update your changes in question, so we can see. And what output you are getting with this echo statement...  echo $quecode[$i]." <--> ".$answer[$i]."<br/>";

Comment: Got It Thank you M Idrees